# Problem with a Linq to Entity query that contains a passed list of entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have two entities

```
User {  UserID, Name, UserTypeID }
StudentParent { StudentParentID, StudentID, ParentID }

// where
UserTypeID { 1=student, 2=parent }
```

Both `StudentParent.StudentID` and `StudentParent.ParentID` are foreign keys pointing to `User.UserID`

I have a list of Students (`IEnumerable<User>`) that I need to get the list of parents for.  I need help figuring out the proper expression to get the list of parents.

Should I be using a contains or any statement to match against the list of Student Users?

Comment: This needs to be cleaned up.

When you say you have a list of Students IEnumerable, are all the objects in the list of type User? Is it IEnumerable<User>?

Comment: I am creating a function where I am passing in an IEnumerable<User> list called students. In the function I am trying to get all the parents(which are also of type User) for those students I am passing in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to `Select` the `Parent` entites from your `IEnumerable` of students.

```
students.SelectMany(s => s.StudentParents.Select(sp => sp.ntParent_Parent));
```

This performs a projection from your collection of students, not all `Students`.

Logically it is something like

- here's a set of students
- for each of those students, get the student parent entities
- for each of those studentparent entities, get the parent

It also may be more useful to select into an anonymous type so you can see which parents belong to which students.

```
students.Select(s => new { 
    Student = s,
    Parents = s.StudentParents.Select(sp => sp.ntParent_Parent))});
```

Comment: My navigational properties in the User entity are StudentParent_Parent and StudentParent_Student.   But I also need to only get the parents from the IEnumerable list of students I am passing in.